# VK.NET cannot access child value

Tags: c#

Получаю список друзей и вылетает с ошибкой

```
cannot access child value on newtonsoft.json.linq.jvalue
```

Думаю виновато отчество у людей в профиле - можно ли как то обойти это?

Comment: Добавь код.....

Comment: @codename0082016 var message = vk.Messages.Send(new VkNet.Model.RequestParams.MessagesSendParams
{
UserId = 423741868,
Message = $"{friends.LastName}{friends.FirstName} : URL - {friends.Domain}"
});

Comment: vk.net вообще поддерживается ? Возможно, поменялось api, вот и не парсится json. Надо править.

Comment: а то можно использовать за место vknet?

Comment: А почему бы вам не использовать свои знания, а не готовую библиотеку, что бы получить список друзей просто создайте функцию возвращаюию лист.